# Can't get x-ttcidfont to load correctly in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wkhtmltopdf, xvfb

I'm using the command below in coordination with wkhtmltopdf to generate screenshots from html/web pages. I can't get xvfb to run, it just hangs. I got the following error

```
[dix] Could not init font path element /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType, removing from list!
```

The command that I am running

```
xvfb-run -e "/home/my_dir/errors" -a -s "-screen 0 1280x1024x24" wkhtmltopdf http://google.com output.pdf
```

Wkhtmltopdf works just fine, am just trying to get xserver to work so the screenshots look more realistic.

This occurs on ubuntu 12.04

I've ran the following commands[from google searches], and am unsure as to what I should do next...

```
sudo apt-get install -y x11-xkb-utils
sudo apt-get install -y xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic
sudo apt-get install -y x-ttcidfont-conf cabextract ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudo dpkg-reconfigure --default-priority x-ttcidfont-conf
```